# match "IF" or "If" not preceded with a dollar sign

Tags: regex, pcre

Just can't figure out how I match IF and If but not if or ones prefixed $.

examples:

```
If True then // <- match 
    
IF True then // <- match 
    
if True then // <- don't match (lowercase i)
     
{SIF NOT DEFINED(SAAS)} // <- don't match (part of another word)
{$IFDEF DEBUG} // <- don't match (preceded with a $)
```

ChatGPT suggests:

```
\bIf\b(?!\$)
```

but it doesn't work when there's a `$` before.

Comment: try this once : `\b[Ii][Ff]\b(?![\w$])`

Comment: _Just can't figure out how I match IF and IF_. At least re-read your question.

Comment: (?![\w$]) => I used a negative lookahead assertion to ensure that the matched "IF" or "If" is not followed by a word character (\w) or a dollar sign ($).

Comment: \b[Ii][Ff]\b(?![\w$]) don't work because it'll match lower case if.

Comment: There was typo for sure. If and IF. But the code example should cover all cases

Comment: (?-i)\b[I][Ff]\b(?![\w$])

That seems to work in regex101 but not on my environment, maybe library is not latest or something else:

 https://regex101.com/r/WGrqGa/1

Comment: @DavidTeo: `(?![\w$])`: The `\w` is redundant here since the this lookahead comes after a letter and a word-boundary. Also, the `$` is forbidden before the `If` or the `IF`, not after.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use lookahead or lookbehind here, since you want to match the terms `If` and `IF` only as a whole word. Simply use word boundaries:

```
\bI[Ff]\b
```